# text wrapping for titles

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[This question](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76) gets the last letter of the first line cut off.

I don't know if it's just me but it does it in both Firefox and Chrome:

[image: text cut off]

I'm on Windows 7 and running at 1280x1024 if that's relevant.

Comment: It looks right for me in both browsers; it wraps just after "SE"

Comment: IE8 on XP here, it cuts off the prongs of the E just as on your screenshot for me.

Comment: Is it a font-related question?  Firebug seems to suggest the effective font stack is Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif; for that element.

Comment: Press Ctrl+ or Ctrl- to repro the problem.

Comment: Repro in Win7 + FF 3.6.13. I suspect this is isolated to just that site and its design.

Answer (score 4):

The fix will be in the next deployment.

**EDIT:** This is now completed.